# SQL Server - can I let the IDENTITY_INSERT as ON forever?

Tags: sql, sql-server, identity-column

I have a super big table, more than 404 million rows, with an Identity column, but we don't use that table anymore, we only send certain data to it, is it possible to execute only once the `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON` and never need to use it again?

What I want is to avoid any failure by the identity column during the inserts.
If I execute only that line it will remain forever or it's by session?

Thanks

Comment: Does not seem to be a secure idea.. can't you alter the field and make it not identity?

Comment: [Edit] the question and tag the DBMS you're talking about.

Comment: @MundoPeter that's not possible in SQL Server, the only way to achieve that it's deleting the column, but as I have so many rows it's very time consuming to clone the column and drop the identity one. I also tried to copy everything to a new table without the Identity but again it's very expensive in time and space

Comment: You can do this (remove identity property) as a metadata only operation with ALTER TABLE ... SWITCH

Answer (score 4):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15  says :

> At any time, only one table in a session can have the IDENTITY_INSERT
> property set to ON. If a table already has this property set to ON,
> and a SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON statement is issued for another table,
> SQL Server returns an error message that states SET IDENTITY_INSERT is
> already ON and reports the table it is set ON for.

So, you'll have to set the identity_insert on every new session, and you're limited to only one table at a time per session.

You'll be better fixing the table, especially if "you don't use that table  anymore".  If the identity doesn't matter anymore, remove it.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's what I'll do.